# HTML - Hover En un "Div a" que afecte las propiedades de otro "Div a"

Tags: jquery, css, html5, hover

Espero pueda ayudarme y espero también pueda darme a entender para facilitar su redacción.

Me dispuse a crear un "menú" en forma de barra, dicha barra coloqué en la parte izquierda de mi página, de tal manera que todos los "items" o botones de dicho menú estuviesen colocados uno sobre otro de manera vertical, estos botones están solamente conformados por iconos, como se pueden ver en el siguiente código:

```
<div class="slidebar" id="div1">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></i></a>
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
    .slidebar{
    background: #04B486;
    /*margin-top: 70px;
    padding-top: 30px;*/
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 120px;
  }
  .slidebar a{
    width: 57px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;

    padding-left: 15px;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-decoration: none;


    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;

  }

  .slidebar a:hover{
    background: #f4f5f9;
    color: #04B486;

  }
```

---

El **problema** es que necesito que los items y abajo tengan sus respectivos bordes también al momento de hacer **hover** en un ítem, de manera que si hago el hover sobre cualquier ítem, el ítem de arriba tenga borres en la parte inferior izquierda, y el ítem de abajo tenga su borde en la parte superior derecha, como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Menú Deseado]

Como pudieron darse cuenta, lo bordes de los otros "Div A" están resaltados al momento de realizar un Hover.

Espero haberme dado a entender, a su vez, también espero me puedan ayudar para poder resolver mi duda, es lo principal, lograr lo mismo que la imagen de color rosa. También agradezco aquella persona que me corrigiera la estructuración de mi código en dado caso que estuviera mal estructurado.
Agradezco cada uno de sus comentarios y el apoyo también, es la primera vez que publico por aquí, espero puedan entender el desorde.

Comment: Lo que deseas es lo que esta en la imagen?

Comment: Si !, justo lo que está en la imagen.

Comment: Así como lo tienes esta bien, no entiendo el problema.

Comment: Ah disculpa, verás en la imagen se muestra una barra de color rosa, supongamos que se le aplicó un hover (al ítem de usuario de la imagen), si te das cuenta la parte superior derecha e inferior izquierda de dicho hover contienen unos bordes o contornos, dichos bordes o contornos mi código no los tiene termina en vertices. Espero haberme dado a entender.

Comment: Espero que te sirva, la actualización de la respuesta.

Comment: Justo eso era, te lo agradezco de corazón, ahora solamente me queda programarlo para que se quede fijo el hover cada vez que alguien da clic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto cumple con lo que deseas, solo es un ejemplo de como debería ser, mi idea fue poner un contenedor arriba y abajo de cada opción (puedes usar `:before`..), y generarle una curva

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[aqui](https://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/) hay otro ejemplo

```css
.slidebar {
  background: #04B486;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}

.slidebar a {
  width: 57px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.principal:hover a {
  background: white;
  color: #04B486;
}

.principal:hover .antes {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
.principal:hover .antes .antes1 {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #04B486;
}
.principal:hover .despues {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
.principal:hover .despues .despues1 {
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #04B486;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="slidebar" id="div1">
  <diV class="principal">
    <diV class="antes">
      <div class="antes1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <diV class="despues">
      <div class="despues1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <diV class="principal">
    <diV class="antes">
      <div class="antes1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <diV class="despues">
      <div class="despues1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <diV class="principal">
    <diV class="antes">
      <div class="antes1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <diV class="despues">
      <div class="despues1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <diV class="principal">
    <diV class="antes">
      <div class="antes1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <diV class="despues">
      <div class="despues1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es un ejemplo con `:before`

```css
.slidebar {
  background: #04B486;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}

.slidebar a {
  width: 57px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.principal:hover a {
  background: white;
  color: #04B486;
}

.principal:hover::before {
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #04B486;
  position: absolute;
  width: 65px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
}

.principal:hover .antes::after {
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #04B486;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 65px;
  border-top-right-radius: 16px;
}

.principal:hover .antes {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

.principal:hover .despues {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="slidebar" id="div1">
  <diV class="principal">
    <diV class="antes"></div>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <diV class="despues"></div>
  </div>
  <diV class="principal">
    <diV class="antes"></div>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>    </a>
    <diV class="despues"></div>
  </div>
  <diV class="principal">
    <diV class="antes"></div>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <diV class="despues"></div>
  </div>
  <diV class="principal">
    <diV class="antes"></div>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <diV class="despues"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho, de corazón. Justo eso es lo que estaba buscando. Muchas gracias.